# How to make a dynamic size layouts using HTML and CSS that expand to the bottom of a browser window without fixed heights

Tags: html, css, layout, browser, cross-browser

I have a problem with dynamic layouts that don't have fixed heights but one of the elements expands to the height of the browser window (fill the screen) and the elements above are sized depending on their content - it is dynamic, so i can't set a fixed height in these elements and using javascript to calculate it is too slow. IT can be done in the latest FF and Chrome, but our company supports older browsers as well, co i'm looking for a way how to fix/hack it in IE9+ and FF24+.

Thanks

This example works in FF32 and latest Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"></head>
<body>
 <div style="position:absolute; top:0;bottom:0;left:0;width:200px;">
  <table style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    ">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <div style="font-weight: bold;" contenteditable="true">
       Content editable, please write something here multi-line and watch how the Lorem Ipsum part behaves.<br/><br/><br/>Lorem ipsum starts under this message.
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="
       position: relative;
       height: 100%;
       ">
     <div>
      <div style="
        overflow-y: scroll;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        ">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras velit enim, commodo et ultricies quis, volutpat non velit. Ut sit amet nisl sit amet justo molestie interdum non eu mi. Mauris vitae facilisis dui. Nunc ultrices nulla vel faucibus aliquam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque quam neque, rhoncus id purus a, porta auctor sem. Donec consequat pretium mi vel imperdiet. Ut ac nibh eros.

     Proin nec consectetur magna. Fusce interdum sapien nec nisl dictum, vitae facilisis sem consectetur. Donec convallis, tellus id venenatis elementum, erat enim dignissim libero, at rutrum nibh ligula nec justo. Cras id leo turpis. In ut arcu tempor, viverra elit volutpat, molestie metus. Etiam ut rutrum enim. Nulla sed diam quis lectus tempor tempus. Integer volutpat nec dui a interdum.

     Donec eu ultrices elit, at volutpat mi. Donec porttitor consequat adipiscing. Proin pellentesque felis et scelerisque feugiat. In interdum blandit lorem, quis vulputate sem dictum at. Donec et eros a elit condimentum luctus. Aenean ut nisl nulla. Curabitur id libero aliquam, congue lectus non, ullamcorper augue. Nulla quis nisi commodo, eleifend enim vel, rhoncus orci. Sed nec metus nec massa varius tempor nec nec justo. Praesent sagittis et metus eget pretium. Integer pretium ante eu elit tempor consectetur. Integer auctor sapien lectus, malesuada rutrum turpis fringilla quis. Donec convallis pulvinar dolor ut laoreet. Integer nec enim felis. In eu massa varius, pharetra erat varius, pellentesque magna. Pellentesque gravida risus quis risus ullamcorper lacinia.

     Suspendisse congue purus et quam vehicula, eu facilisis justo iaculis. Proin ut tellus est. Nullam egestas, turpis id accumsan hendrerit, nulla nisl congue lacus, at varius lorem ligula in ligula. Maecenas vulputate sapien erat, eget porttitor urna rhoncus ut. Nullam aliquam lectus ut scelerisque fermentum. Aenean vel elit eu nulla eleifend venenatis et a purus. In at enim at ipsum semper laoreet at in justo.

     Quisque at risus at nisi ornare pellentesque. Praesent nec purus nec erat sodales facilisis sed ut odio. Maecenas ullamcorper lacinia faucibus. Donec ultrices ornare egestas. Aenean in ornare dolor, scelerisque ultricies purus. Vivamus vel elementum diam. Praesent non ligula ac turpis vestibulum feugiat.
       </div>
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 <div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body></html>
```